# buffer text for output in c

Tags: c, file, text, buffer, output

I'm trying to make a sequencer in C that handles text files with characters 'a' 'b' '%' etc, and then display's them in a sequence, one at a time, so I would like to buffer them somehow, but I'm not very familiar with the topic. But my idea is

a) store them in an array (restrict the dimension of characters in each file)

b) read them on the fly.

But I'm not sure how to implement this in the fastest output possible. Has anyone dealt with a lot of text files and them having to output them in a big chunk like this?

Comment: It is not yet at all clear what you're trying to do.  Do you have a number of open text files, (say 3 of them, A, B and C), and you need to output one character from A, then one from B, then one from C?  If so, doesn't `<stdio.h>` and a `FILE *` give you enough buffering?  If not, please start from the beginning and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Could you give some examples of the type of input(s) and the desired output(s)? Are you desiring to output to another file or `stdout`? Can you define what "a lot" of text files is? All I get right now is that you're debating the speed of storing data in dynamic vs. static memory while you sequence the data before writing it back; frankly that's going to be peanuts compared to the I/O speed.

Comment: yeah I want the program to detect a range of text files within a given directory, say 50 text files, and display them in a time sequence, so with some sleep intervals in between each one. Maybe FILE is good enough for this procedure I was just wondering if creating your own buffer that could be fetched from would speed things up. So if I use FILE is fgets/freads good to use? I have read one char at a time and that went kind of slow, I hope i'm being clear on this

Comment: ahh actually I found a useful answer by you Leffler :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669933/default-input-and-output-buffering-for-fopend-files?rq=1

Comment: I'm glad you found some help.  When you're asked to clarify a question, please edit the question, rather than adding comments.  It's simpler for people coming later to find out what you're asking about (and provide answers) if the question contains the information.  I'm still not completely clear what your scenario is, but from what I can guess, you're unlikely to need facilities that `FILE *` operations do not provide.  So, I recommend that you plan on using the standard file operations until you have a clear scenario where they can't do what you need.